# Peat Pellet Problem, Root bound after Transplanting

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes, transplanting, wilt, peat

These tomato plants started out very well in [30 mm peat pellets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005HGCT9C) purchased on Amazon.

[image]

After transplanting into a grow bag of Miracle Gro Potting Mix,

[image]

they continued to grow well for a few weeks then stopped growing, turned yellow, and wilted.

[image]

I removed the plants from the grow bags

[image]

The roots appear to have had a difficult time breaking through the netting of the peat pot.

Has anyone seen a similar yellowing problem?  Peat pellets or not.

Comment: I think the most obvious problem is that you are attempting to grow plants in essentially transparent "pots". Roots from most plants do not do well when exposed to sunlight. The internet is rife with info on why you shouldn't use transparent pots.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar story - I saw a recommendation online that talked about putting some peat mix in paper pulp egg cartons, sowing seeds in them and then planting out the separated egg cups with soil and growing seedlings intact into the soil. Only about half of mine survived. The fails were pulled out of the ground by birds and other critters wanting to see what was underneath or simply dried out. Those that survived managed to stay constantly moist. I figure that any exposed cup edges wicked moisture out of the paper leaving a dry layer between moist roots and the moist ground. So the roots were never able to find their way out *ad extra* but were confined *ad intra* and so perished.

Trying this with tomato might be okay but next time around I would make sure to bury the "pot" completely so that nothing is visible above ground and absolutely keep moist at all times. Or just pull the pot off before planting and throw it on the compost pile.

Comment: I have found that it is easy to remove the webbing around the peat. From now on I am going to remove the webbing when I transplant.